# Border of rectangle are not rotated with transform on android (react native)

Tags: android, react-native

I want to do a percentage border circle on android with react native. I used [react-native-percentage-circle](https://github.com/JackPu/react-native-percentage-circle) to custom. But I'm facing the issues about rotating a half of a circle that a border not rotate like content of circle

[image]

Like the image, the gray content of circle did rotate with percent is 5%, but border doesn't rotate, only change position.
Please help me how to rotate entirely rectangle of the half circle

If I remove border radius of a half of circle, the border works right

[image]

Comment: If I remove borderRadius, the border of a rectangle works right

Comment: Maybe borderRadius and borderWidth cannot work together in this case